# Databasing in Ruby

Tags: php, ruby

I'm making a website for a group that needs a database. The data is going to store user information among other things. I already know PHP and could easily do it in PHP, but to further myself as a developer, I'd like to learn a language like Ruby. I know how to use databases in PHP. But, when writing Ruby, can I use SQL databases?

Answer (score 2):

We don't know how you call your database in PHP.
Many PHP users use MySQL and call sql statements with the embedded mysql driver,
and then iterate over the results.
You can do this also in Ruby. The mysql driver is not embedded, But you can easily install it with RubyGems. You need the mysql2 gem.
https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2

But if want to be more object-oriented, there is the framework "Ruby On Rails" with "ActiveRecord" for database connection. Here you don't write SQL directly, instead you specify what objects you want to have or store (except in rare edge cases, where you still can write sql)
This needs some learning time. But then it is lot less coding, code is better readable, and security errors like are also easier to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

The basic answer is yes - you can do something like that using Ruby and a framework like ActiveRecord or Sequel, but this far too broad for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Good afternoon.
Depends on the speed you need .
1) If you need quickly - write on PHP
2) If you have some time and want learn Ruby On Rails, ActiveRecord etc. ... buy some book for beginner, read doc and step by step create application

Comment: I actually don't have a timeframe and wanted to use this as an excuse to learn Ruby. Good to know it can do it!